# How to animate a cursor using the sequence of images?

Tags: c++, linux, gtk, cursor, gtkmm

I want to animate a cursor each time I click on a window. So, I have a sequence of images and I am curious about is it possible to animate a cursor this way. For now I have the code which just replaces one cursor with another without any animations. Probably here I should deal with css? Thank you in advance

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Window> ref_window;
ref_window = window->get_window();
Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Cursor> cursor = Gdk::Cursor::create(ref_window->get_display(), Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_file("./push_cursor_25fps_4.png", 20, 20), 0, 0);
ref_window->set_cursor(cursor);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I once explored that Windows supports animated cursors - concerning other platforms, I'm not sure. If you already managed to replace the cursor you are (IMHO) half there. Just use your sequence of images and add a timeout signal which replaces the cursor shape periodically.

Comment: Btw. when I was toying with animated cursors in Windows I realized that I got annoyed by them rather soon in daily business and replaced them again by the (non-animated) standard shapes. ;-)

Comment: You are right, the timeout could be a solution) But I think that gtkmm should give a better solution for this purpose

Comment: Could you please give me a hint, how did you set up the animated cursor on Windows?

Comment: I don't know anymore. Somehow like this (probably): [How to use custom mouse cursors in Windows](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/windows10-custom-mouse-cursors/) (Sorry, it's a while ago that I did this.)